# Image Texture material not showing properly on faces

Tags: materials, image, transparency

I have a problem with an assigned material.

For the context: I have created a PNG image with Photoshop and saved it in PNG. Once I've done that, I went to blender, created a new material with the image texture node plugged into color and alpha channel. The preview shows me the correct visualisation but once I applied through an additional slots, but I get a full black rectangle instead in the render.

Do you have any idea how I can get this to display only the black part of my PNG?
Is there also a way to get some volume from the visible part of the PNG (visible = non-transparent parts of my image)?

Here is the original image (the PNG):
[image]

Here is my material nodes:
[image]

And finally the slot window:

[image]

Here you can see what I currently have with it:
[image]

Comment: If you are using EEVEE, you need to change the **Blend Mode** of your material (the transparent one) from _Opaque_ to something else (Alpha-Blend often works well)

Comment: Is it UV mapped?

Comment: Hi Nathan, 
Yes, the whole object is mapped.